# How to switch for-loop declared in a variable

Tags: python, for-loop

```
input = [ID[w] for w in word] + [0]*(A-B)
```

This is the original code that I wrote. But, I just want to make sure if it is same as
code below.

```
for w in word :
   input = ID[w] + [0]*(A-B)
```

Comment: Well, can  run the code and check the if the output is equal?

Comment: `input` should be a `list` and you chould `append()` to this list. And after `for`-loop you should add `[0]*(A-B)`

Answer (score 0):

Code

```
input = [ID[w] for w in word] + [0]*(A-B)
```

means

```
input = [ID[w] for w in word]
input += [0]*(A-B)
```

and this means

```
input = []

for w in word: 
    input.append(ID[w])

input += [0]*(A-B)
```